# How do I solve "CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Task""?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am still new to Node JS. I am trying to make a book directory using Node JS and Mongo DB. Every time I press the delete button to delete a book it shows me this error

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model 
"Task"
BSONTypeError: Argument passed in must be a string of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters
```

This my `server.js`:

```
app.delete("/api/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { id: id } = req.params;
  console.log(id);
  const task = await Task.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
  if (!task) {
     return res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with id :${id}` });
  }
  res.status(200).json(task);
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so i was getting this error -> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value ...

1. I log the id out and checked if it corresponded to my id in my Database
2. since i confirmed it was there and still getting the same error, I then used .trim() method to remove any blank space from the _id and the error was solved

check my code below  and see if it helps

```js
const checkItemId = req.body.checkbox;
    console.log(checkItemId);

    // find the item by id and remove it make sure youuse .trim to remove any blank space
    Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkItemId.trim(), (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            console.log("Removed Succesfull");
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem once.
I got this error because the ObjectId passed in through the params didn't existed in my database. Hence, this threw an exception.

Workaround for this:

```
 //add this line as a check to validate if object id exists in the database or not
 if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) 
            return res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with id :${id}` });
```

Updated code:

```
app.delete("/api/books/:id", async (req, res) => {
try {
  const { id: id } = req.params;
  console.log(id);
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) 
      return res.status(404).json({ msg: `No task with id :${id}` 
  });
  const task = await Task.findOneAndDelete({ _id: id });
  res.status(200).json(task);
 } catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
});
```

Comment: But how do I make my id valid?

Comment: @Amr you can't do anything to make it valid. It is something provided by mongoDB and you can't make any changes in it otherwise it will give error. You can make sure that if you are storing the ID in a variable in client side or server side, make that variable ```const``` so that nobody can change it.

Comment: THIS MY ID: {
  _id: new ObjectId("6236d529d4d3d7ce088769e1"),
  title: 'HelloWorld',
  image: 'https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51WApJ4MiLL.jpg',
  author: 'Sarah J. Maas',
  desc: 'HEllo lekdlwlkelwkd',
  __v: 0
}

Comment: Are you calling the route as /api/books/6236d529d4d3d7ce088769e1 or like /api/books/ObjectId("6236d529d4d3d7ce088769e1") ?

Comment: nvm... i am calling  /api/books/6236d529d4d3d7ce088769e1. Thanks

Comment: But how does it know if is is valid or not, without checking inside the db itself? (I see that a check is sync)

Answer (score 0):

Check if below code working!

```
    if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(id)) {
      throw new HttpException('Not a valid ID!', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
      return id;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by removing blank space in my id ,use `const id = req.params.id`
then `const trimmed_id = id.trim()`, pass `trimmed_id` on your `findById`

it will work